How to get details of an Azure AD group from az cli
I am trying to get the following information from an Azure group. (my plan is to delete any of the unnecessary groups that are floating here and there with 0 users, 0 groups, 0 group memberships (that it is a not a part of other groups) and 0 owners`)

Total direct members
User(s)
Group(s)
Group memberships
Owners
Total members

I am trying the following commands:
# Get total direct members
total_direct_members=$(az ad group member list --group "$group_id" --query "length([])" --output tsv)

# Get users in the group
total_users=$(az ad group member list --group "$group_id" --query "[?objectType=='User'] | length([])" --output tsv)

# Get groups in the group
total_groups=$(az ad group member list --group "$group_id" --query "[?objectType=='Group'] | length([])" --output tsv)

# Get group memberships
group_memberships=$(az ad group list --filter "id eq '$group_id'" --query "[].displayName" --output tsv)

# Get owners
owners=$(az ad group owner list --group "$group_id" --query "[].displayName" --output tsv)
total_owners=$(echo "$owners" | wc -l)

I also tried az rest
# Get total direct members
total_direct_members=$(az rest --method GET --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$group_id/members" --query "value | length(@)" --output tsv)

# Get users in the group
total_users=$(az rest --method GET --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$group_id/members" --query "value[?['@odata.type'] == '#microsoft.graph.user'] | length(@)" --output tsv)

# Get groups in the group
total_groups=$(az rest --method GET --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$group_id/members" --query "value[?['@odata.type'] == '#microsoft.graph.group'] | length(@)" --output tsv)

# Get group memberships
group_memberships=$(az rest --method GET --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf" --query "[?id == '$group_id'].displayName" --output tsv)

# Get owners
owners=$(az rest --method GET --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$group_id/owners" --query "value[].displayName" --output tsv)
total_owners=$(echo "$owners" | wc -l)

# Get total members
total_members=$total_direct_members

But I can only see the value for total_direct_members when I the actual group has Owners and Groups.
There are other groups with that has all the above data and my output is still the same.
Can someone help me understand where I am doing the mistake?

are u following any document?

Do you want to delete the group when all the conditions(0 users, 0 groups, ) owner) met or If one of the condition are met ?

Have you considered the graph api?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group id}/members
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Hi @JulianHüppauff this shows "0" owners even for the groups that has owners. And as I am using the az rest it is as same as the graph explorer I believe

To list the groups, with zero members, zero owner and zero group membership :
Use below az rest code snippet:
# Get all groups
groups=$(az rest --method GET --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups" --query "value[].id" -o tsv)

for groupId in $groups; do
  # Get members of the group
  members=$(az rest --method GET --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupId/members" --query "value" -o tsv)

  # Get owners of the group
  owners=$(az rest --method GET --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupId/owners" --query "value" -o tsv)

 #Get GroupMembership
groupMemberships=$(az rest --method GET --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupId/transitiveMembers" --query "value" -o tsv)

  # Check if there are no members and no owners
  if [ -z "$members" ] && [ -z "$owners" ] && [ -z "$groupMemberships"]; then
    echo "Group with ID $groupId has zero members, zero owners and zero group membership."
  fi
done


Output:


To delete groups, with zero members, zero owner and zero group membership.
Use below az rest code snippet:
# Get all groups
groups=$(az rest --method GET --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups" --query "value[].id" -o tsv)

for groupId in $groups; do
  # Get members of the group
  members=$(az rest --method GET --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupId/members" --query "value" -o tsv)

  # Get owners of the group
  owners=$(az rest --method GET --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupId/owners" --query "value" -o tsv)

  # Get group memberships
  groupMemberships=$(az rest --method GET --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupId/transitiveMembers" --query "value" -o tsv)

  # Check if there are no members, no owners, and no group memberships
  if [ -z "$members" ] && [ -z "$owners" ] && [ -z "$groupMemberships" ]; then
    echo "Group with ID $groupId has zero members, zero owners, and zero group membership. Deleting..."

    # Delete the group
    az rest --method DELETE --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupId"

    echo "Group with ID $groupId deleted."
  fi
done


Reference:
az group | Microsoft Learn

Hi Pratik, thank you for your comprehensive answer. This is really helpful. However, I still some groups filter by this code has owners and group memberships :(

Which type of groups they are?
